# How do I configure Juju for use on Azure?

Tags: juju

I usually setup my entire stack with apt-get packages, however I thought I might give Juju a try. I'm using a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.04 on Azure.

I managed to install install the `juju` package and create the config file by running `juju generate-config -w`. However, I can't seem to move any further.

Attempting to run `juju boostrap` results in an error which requests that I provide an `access-key` or `secret-key`. I have no idea where to find these credentials or if I should be using `OpenStack` mode?

I could not seem to find any documentation specifically for configuring Juju on an Azure Ubuntu VM.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juju now fully supports Windows Azure (https://azure.microsoft.com/).

Install the latest version of Juju:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/

Juju is already aware of the configuration required to access Azure, but you will need to activate some services on your Azure account and collect some credential information to allow Juju to access it:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/help-azure

Comment: Seems like it still didn't change. Ran over the same problem today. Why is JuJu listed here then?: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/partner-solutions/

Comment: A comment from [Luke B](http://askubuntu.com/users/185668/luke-b) (that was posted as an answer): _I'm guessing this has not yet been implemented?_